# In-App Purchase API Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I am creating an application with shopping. When I run the command to fetch the products.

```
ListingInformation li = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationAsync();
```

It shows the following error:

```
Exception from HRESULT: 0x805A0194
```

What could generate this error?

Comment: Could you provide more context for the error?  Is there a stacktrace generated, perhaps?

Comment: Hi.

I am creating an application with shopping and developing for Windows Store 8.1.
I created in the application IAPs panel to my application products and has set up in Package.appxmanifest the application ID .

When I enter the application and seek the registered products :
 ListingInformation li = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationAsync ();

It 's the following error: Exception from HRESULT: 0x805A0194

You must publish the application ? Or is it necessary to make other settings besides Package.appxmanifest .